# Report-To header Content-Security-Policy for C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-security-policy

### I'm trying to add the report-to directive to my CSP (in Startup Configure, C# ASP.NET)

My report-uri is working but is deprecated. Report-to is intended to replace report-uri, but both should be specified for backward compatibility (report-uri will be ignored if report-to is present) [Reporting directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#reporting_directives)

As I understand [Report-uri](https://report-uri.com/), I'll need to setup a "Reporting API" with the 'Report-To' header similar to:

```json
Report-To: {
  "group":"csp-endpoint",
  "max_age":31536000,
  "endpoints":[{"url":"https://MYENDPOINT"}],
  "include_subdomains":true
}
```

and then point to the groupname in my directive - something like:

`"report-to csp-endpoint;"`

I can't make it work with above JSON.

I've tried several things *(in my Startup.cs Configure)*:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
  context.Response.Headers.Add(
    "Report-To",
    @"{""group"":""csp-endpoint"",""max_age"":31536000,""endpoints"":[{""url"":""https:// /*...*/ ""}]}"
  );
  context.Response.Headers.Add(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    /* ... */
    "report-to csp-endpoint;"
    // (also tried to use default as name)
  );
});
```

as well as other ways to do the same thing, e.g.:

- using a class with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` *(resulting in something like above string)*
- using StringValues: StringValues try = new[] { "Group='default'", "MaxAge=10886400", "Endpoints='" + @"https://...
- writing the (JSON) string directly together with report-to

I have searched quite a lot but can only find references to the reporting api with Report-To and the JSON, but not quite the code in C#.

(I think it can be done with a webconfig but it ought to be possible to add together with my other CSP-directives in my Configure).

I'm sure this will be amazingly straightforward, when demonstrated I just haven't succeeded yet.

An **example with code** would therefore be highly appreciated

Comment: the question is if you should wait with report-to until more browsers supports it? https://caniuse.com/?search=report-to

Comment: Maybe you're right Tore. I think it is annoying that I can't make it work though, it should be easy ?!
Also according to your link it is supported in Edge, Chrome and a few more, so that already covers a lot, and with report-uri as a fallback, there should not be any compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some old code I wrote to experiment with it, but not 100% sure if it still works or not.

```
private void SetHeaders()
{
    string reportTo = @"
{""group"":""default"",
""max_age"":31536000,
""endpoints"":[{""url"":""https://edument.report-uri.com/a/d/g""}],
""include_subdomains"":true}
";

    //Remove all duplicate spaces and line-breaks
    reportTo = reportTo.Replace("\r", " ");
    reportTo = reportTo.Replace("\n", " ");

    while (reportTo.Contains("  "))  //yes, ugly hack....
        reportTo = reportTo.Replace("  ", " ");

    Response.AppendHeader("Report-To", reportTo);
    Response.AppendHeader("NEL", "{\"report_to\":\"default\",\"max_age\":31536000,\"include_subdomains\":true, \"failure_fraction\": 1.0}");
    Response.AppendHeader("Feature-Policy", "geolocation 'none'");
}
```

Comment: Hmm .. Still couldn't make it work :(
I had to use context.Response.Headers.Append as I couldn't use AppendHeader ?!
(My context is a HttpContext) Is there any reason for the use of Append instead of Add?
Thx for the effort

Comment: Worked for me. Just needed the Report-To header in my case. Thanks